# What is the difference between MVUE and UMVUE

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I was going through the minimum variance unbiased estimators and I am confused about the concept of MVUE and UMVUE. Is the unbiased estimator whose variance attaining CRLB a UMVUE or MVUE? I referred two books. One of those(A first course on parametric inference by B.K.Kale ) says that the unbiased estimator attaining CRLB is MVUE and the other(An introduction to probability and statistics by Rohatgi) says that it is UMVUE. So, are they same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "uniform" in UMVUE is sometimes added to emphasize that the estimator has the smallest variance for all values of the parameter being estimated, not just for a range of values. Although, in practice, the terms MVUE and UMVUE are used interchangeably.

We may have two estimators which are MVUE for different ranges of the parameter theta. However, a UMVUE (if it exists) will have the minimum variance for all values of the parameter being estimated.

Answer (score 4):

MVUE and UMVUE are two different names to the same concept: unbiased estimators that achieve lowest variance among all other unbiased estimators, uniformly in all possible parameters. Consequently, an unbiased estimator that attains Cramer Rao lower bound is MVUE/UMVUE.